# Spring Batch Paging Issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am working on Spring Batch and I am using paging for fetching data from DB. for the first time Its firing Query as expected but for second page its adding one more unexpected parameter. I don't understand why.

My Query in XML file is

```
<bean id="summaryAppReader" scope="step" autowire-candidate="false"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.majesco.nyl.batch.mapper.SummaryApplicationRowMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="VIEW_SUMMARY_APPLICATION" />
            <property name="selectClause"
                value="application_id, upper(application_status)  as application_status,relationship_code, create_date,submission_date,transmission_date,TRANSMISSION_STATUS,tpa_notes,site_details_id,transaction_num,PROCESS_STATUS,process_date,application_status_date,first_name,middle_name,last_name,suffix,prefix,APPROVED_REJECTED_DATE,action_by,ass_acronym,user_name,applicant_name,site_name,ASSOCIATION_ID, (TO_DATE('#{jobParameters['runDate']}', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - trunc(create_date)) as elapsedDays" />
            <property name="sortKeys">
                <map>
                    <entry key="transaction_num" value="ASCENDING" />
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="whereClause"
                value="(upper(application_status)='PENDING' OR (upper(application_status) IN ('APPROVED','DECLINED') AND trunc(application_status_date) = TO_DATE('#{jobParameters['runDate']}', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) and TRANSACTION_NUM &gt;= :minId and TRANSACTION_NUM &lt;= :maxId" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="minId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[minValue]}" />
            <entry key="maxId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[maxValue]}" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

for fetching data for first page its firing query something like this and its expected

```
Reading page 0
SQL used for reading first page: [SELECT * FROM (SELECT application_id, upper(application_status)  as application_status,relationship_code, create_date,submission_date,transmission_date,TRANSMISSION_STATUS,tpa_notes,site_details_id,transaction_num,PROCESS_STATUS,process_date,application_status_date,first_name,middle_name,last_name,suffix,prefix,APPROVED_REJECTED_DATE,action_by,ass_acronym,user_name,applicant_name,site_name,ASSOCIATION_ID, (TO_DATE('2016-06-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - trunc(create_date)) as elapsedDays FROM VIEW_SUMMARY_APPLICATION WHERE (upper(application_status)='PENDING' OR (upper(application_status) IN ('APPROVED','DECLINED') AND trunc(application_status_date) = TO_DATE('2016-06-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) and TRANSACTION_NUM >= :minId and TRANSACTION_NUM <= :maxId ORDER BY transaction_num ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10]
Using parameterMap:{minId=100000002630, maxId=100000002663}
```

But for the second page its adding one more parameter in Query _TRANSACTION_NUM which is unexpected like

```
Reading page 1
SQL used for reading remaining pages: [SELECT * FROM (SELECT application_id, upper(appication_status)  as application_status,relationship_code, create_date,submission_date,transmission_date,TRANSMISSION_STATUS,tpa_notes,site_details_id,transaction_num,PROCESS_STATUS,process_date,application_status_date,first_name,middle_name,last_name,suffix,prefix,APPROVED_REJECTED_DATE,action_by,ass_acronym,user_name,applicant_name,site_name,ASSOCIATION_ID, (TO_DATE('2016-06-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - trunc(create_date)) as elapsedDays FROM VIEW_SUMMARY_APPLICATION WHERE (upper(application_status)='PENDING' OR (upper(application_status) IN ('APPROVED','DECLINED') AND trunc(application_status_date) = TO_DATE('2016-06-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) and TRANSACTION_NUM >= :minId and TRANSACTION_NUM <= :maxId ORDER BY transaction_num ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 AND ((transaction_num > :_transaction_num))]
Using parameterMap:{minId=100000002596, maxId=100000002629, _transaction_num=100000002622}
```

**FYI. TRANSACTION_NUM is not unique.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to your `sortKeys`. You defined the following:

```
        <property name="sortKeys">
            <map>
                <entry key="transaction_num" value="ASCENDING" />
            </map>
        </property>
```

Spring Batch is using the highest `transaction_num` from page 0 and saying the next page must have a `transaction_num` higher than that.

The framework will increment the bind variable with each page to ensure you keep getting unique results. The problem here is that you realistically need a Primary Key to page correctly otherwise your `pageSize` (default = 10 and seen where it adds `WHERE ROWNUM <= 10` to your query) will cut off some of your records.

Comment: Is your `application_id` unique? If so, I recommend using that as your sort key instead.

Comment: I resoved by changing sort key to Unique Column. And It worked. Thank you.